# iOS pushKit pushRegistry:(PKPushRegistry *)registry didUpdatePushCredentials neverCall in Individual devices

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

1. Is open
2. Capabilities -Push Notifications is Open
3. Background Mode : Voice over IP  open   backgroud fetch open  Remote notifications  open  location updaete open;
   code :
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCxRV.jpg)

Delegate `<PKPushRegistryDelegate>` also observe
but just some device (Especially small probability) never call `didUpdatePushCredentials()` mothod, I tested many times, (uninstall app, install app),it also never call this method, but when I restart device then method called, 
 Has anyone ever been fall in this situation? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Yes, this is the device specific issue which get resolved after restarting the device. i have faced this issue many times in different devices.

Comment: Is this a bug? What if there is such a situation? Pushkit's instructions cannot be executed. We are not allowed to have this situation. What remedy is there? thank you !

Comment: This is the problem only while the app is not installed from App Store and occurs randomly without any specific reason. I also couldn't get any specific reason behind this. But the live users never get this kind of issue.

Comment: Our project is distributed by the enterprise. I have found this problem in log in the official version. It's a sad story. Thank you very much!